# Monkey patching and dispatching

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I have the following situation, a module called `enthought.chaco2` and I have many imports, like `from enthought.chaco.api import ..`

so what's the quickest way to add `chaco.api` and make it dispatch to the correct one?

I tried a few things, for example:

```
import enthought.chaco2 as c2
import enthought
enthought.chaco = c2
```

but it doesn't work.  I might have to create a real module and add it to the path; is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

What is the behavior you're looking for?

You could use `from enthought.chaco import api as ChacoApi` and then address any content from the module through `ChacoApi`, like `ChacoApi.foo()` or `chaco_class = ChacoApi.MyClass()`.

You could use (and that's not recommended) `from enthought.chaco.api import *` and have all the content of the module added to your base namespace.
You could add an `__all__` variable declaration to `chaco`'s `__init__.py` file and have the previous example (with the *) only import what you entered the list `__all__`.

Or you could import specifically any content you might use the way you do right now which is perfectly fine in my opinion...

Comment: I have to make in such a way that "from enthought.chaco.api import x" works fine, even if I have enthought.chaco2 only..  

So importing everything doesn't actually help, since still chaco.api is not found.
I tried to create another package which then imports everything (enghought.chaco.api) but this is also problematic, since then other imports like   
"from enthought.etsconfig.etsconfig import ETSConfig" stop working

Comment: Enthought with etsproxy solved already a similar problem, and in short they recreate the whole namspace and modules structures and imported in each one with the new namespace, which I would like to avoid to do..